# need to enable a button on static HTML page when the URL is up

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to frontend programming. We have a backend application which takes some time to start and we want that until it starts a static webpage should be displayed and a button in the page should be enabled when the application is up.

so i am trying to look for a javascript or jquery code where i can ping my url http://localhost:8080/test and once its up the continue button on the static html page should be enabled.

i am new to the front end development but was trying this :
just to test out if it works i have put the website as google and have put the enable button code if the status is 200

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<h2>The Button Element</h2>
<button type="button" Id = "but1" disabled>Continue</button>
<script>
function enable(el){
const HTTP =  new XMLHttpRequest();
const URL = 'https://google.com';
Http.open("GET",url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
el.disabled = false;
}
};
}
enable(but1);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the above code is not doing anything the button is still disabled. i tried some other options as well but nothing is working for me and i am not able to get the response. some websites also showed that its not possible to ping a URL but since I have no experience in front end programming I am stuck here.

Comment: what are you using for a backend?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're pinging code works, but I do now the following:

Instead of `enable(but1)` do this:

```
document.getElementById("but1").disabled = false;
```

This will enable your button.

Answer (score 0):

write your function in onload

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

The onload event occurs when an object has been loaded.

onload is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<h2>The Button Element</h2>
<button type="button" Id = "but1" disabled>Continue</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById("but1").disabled = false;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e4d3v6nc/

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code:

- You can get an HTML element by its ID using `document.getElementById("id as string")`, not by a variable name of ID
- JS is case-sensitive, so `HTTP !== Http` and so on.

Correcting these problems, your code should look like this:

```js
function enable(el){
  const HTTP =  new XMLHttpRequest();
  const URL = 'https://google.com';
  HTTP.open("GET",URL);
  HTTP.send();
  HTTP.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
      el.disabled = false;
    }
  };
}
enable(document.getElementById('but1'));
```